# Cpp define in classes

Tags: c++

I started C++ programming few weaks ago and i have a question about defining the file of a class in a separate file. This is my code.

## main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Maths.h"
int main() {
  Maths m;
  int s = m.sum(1,2);
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

## Maths.h

```
#ifndef Maths_H
#define Maths_H

class Maths
{
  public:
    int sum(int a, int b);
};

#endif
```

## Maths.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Maths.h"
int Maths::sum(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

Why is it that you can't `#define` the same name as your class name. For example in my script Maths?
https://repl.it/repls/UnwillingFreeHeterodontosaurus

Comment: Besides the problem you have, you should *really* spend some time with a few [good beginners books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) because there are some really big misunderstandings in your code.

Comment: `#define`(s) are textual replacements (macros) done by the pre-processor before the compiler proper runs.  You have defined the macro `Maths` to replace any instance of `Maths` with nothing so now the class line becomes nonsense. `class Maths` becomes `class ` after the pre-processor runs.

Comment: Also, with some compilers you can replace the include guards with `#pragma once`. [#pragma once vs include guards?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1143936)

Comment: The pre-processor runs before compiler so it expands macors: replacing any name with the actual value. Thus in your program: `#define x 7    int x = 0; ` the processor will make it: `int 7 = 0`. Which will produce a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

What you `#define` is called a *macro*, and the preprocessor *replaces* the macros with something.

For example, you define the macro `Maths` to be replaced by nothing, and that's what the preprocessor will do. The definition `class Maths { ... }` will be replaced by `class   { ... }`. Which is not valid.

Since preprocessor macros doesn't live in any specific namespace (they really handled separately from the actual C++ parser) they are global. And to avoid clashes in symbol names, macros are usually spelled with all upper-case letter. In your case you should use `MATHS` instead.

Comment: Sorry for the bad code. I jost wrote it quick i improved it now. And thanks for the help!

Comment: Well now the question isn't making much sense :)

Comment: @L.python Please don't edit your question to incorporate answers, as it will not longer make any sense and the answers would seems wrong or just not very good.

Answer (score 1):

Macros have the compiler replace the text with a defined value. So if for instance you have this macro:

`#define Math`

It will replace all the "Math" occurences with nothing, since you didn't define a value to replace it. Defining it like:

`#define Math 1`

Will replace all occurences of "Math" with the value 1.

As for having to include the base class: The compiler has to know where to find the base class. If you don't include the header containing the base class, the header of the derived class has no way to know where to get the base class from, so it will give a `Undefined reference to ...` error.

You should also place the include guards above any other code. So not like this:

```
#include "Enemy.h"
#ifndef Ninja_H
#define Ninja_H
//...
#endif
```

But like this:

```
#ifndef Ninja_H
#define Ninja_H
#include "Enemy.h"
//...
#endif
```

The include guards are basically there to tell the compiler that it's already parsed that file. If you place code outside of the guards it will likely cause errors. Placing an include like that will disable certain optimisations, which in turn leads to longer compile time. Simply put: there is no benefit placing it like that.